# mysqli_fetch_array results in no array despite query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've tried a lot of things to get meaningful data but it seems I can't get an array after the fetch array function.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); //this does not create an array

echo("rows ".mysqli_num_rows($result)."<br/>"); //rows 1
echo("fields ".mysqli_num_fields($result)."<br/>"); //fields 3
echo($row."<br/>"); //
echo("size ".sizeOf($row)); //size 0
```

I get meaningful data from the query result yet the array size of 0 is puzzling.

Comment: Is that the only call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` you have made? If you `var_dump($row);` immediately after the call to `mysql_fetch_array()` are you seeing row data, or `(bool)false`?

Comment: I have a conditional for fetch_array prior. Im getting NULL for var_dump($row). Is it that I'm calling fetch_array twice on the same result?

Comment: Thanks Michael... that did fix my issue. Calling fetch_array twice to the same array caused some issues which I rectified. Getting meaningful data now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. As you probably found, each call to a fetch function advances the recordset's internal pointer, so you must have arrived at the end of it before your diagnostic checks.